# How to correlate all combination of arrays in an RDD?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I have an RDD from `model.productFeatures()` which returns an RDD in the form of `(id, array("d", (...)))`. For example:

```
(1, array("d", (0, 1, 2)))
(2, array("d", (4, 3, 2)))
(3, array("d", (5, 3, 0)))
...
```

I would like to calculate the pairwise correlation between each array, then return for each `id` another `id` whose array has the highest correlation.

Comment: Hey I'm not understanding the maths part of it can you explain it in layman terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need is to get all pairs of elements, except the "diagonal" where they're the same.

```
>>> rdd.cartesian(rdd).filter(lambda (x, y): x != y).collect()
[((1, array('d', [0.0, 1.0, 2.0])), (2, array('d', [4.0, 3.0, 2.0]))),    
 ((1, array('d', [0.0, 1.0, 2.0])), (3, array('d', [5.0, 3.0, 0.0]))), 
 ((2, array('d', [4.0, 3.0, 2.0])), (1, array('d', [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]))), 
 ((3, array('d', [5.0, 3.0, 0.0])), (1, array('d', [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]))), 
 ((2, array('d', [4.0, 3.0, 2.0])), (3, array('d', [5.0, 3.0, 0.0]))), 
 ((3, array('d', [5.0, 3.0, 0.0])), (2, array('d', [4.0, 3.0, 2.0])))]
```

Then a function to calculate the correlation and rearrange to prepare for the last step. Let's assume by "correlation" you mean what is done by [`numpy.correlate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html).

```
def corr_pair(((id1, a1), (id2, a2))):
    return id1, (id2, np.correlate(a1, a2)[0])

>>> rdd.cartesian(rdd).filter(lambda (p1, p2): p1 != p2).map(corr_pair).collect()
[(1, (2, 7.0)), (1, (3, 3.0)), (2, (1, 7.0)), (3, (1, 3.0)), (2, (3, 29.0)), (3, (2, 29.0))]
```

To get the 2nd ID with the maximum correlation with each 1st ID, you can use `reduceByKey` and always keep the bigger one:

```
def keep_higher((id1, c1), (id2, c2)):    
    if c1 > c2:
        return id1, c1
    else:
        return id2, c2

>>> rdd.cartesian(rdd).filter(lambda (x, y): x != y).map(corr_pair).reduceByKey(keep_higher).collect()
[(1, (2, 7.0)), (2, (3, 29.0)), (3, (2, 29.0))]
```